# Не устанавливается libpq-dev

Tags: ubuntu, devops

Собственно, из заголовка вопроса видно в чем проблема.

При попытке установить libpq-dev:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Некоторые пакеты не могут быть установлены. Возможно, то, что вы просите,
неосуществимо, или же вы используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где
запрошенные вами пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация, возможно, вам поможет:

Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 libpq-dev : Зависит: libpq5 (= 12.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) но 13.0-1.pgdg20.04+1 должен быть установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки: у вас зафиксированы сломанные пакеты.
```

Помогите пожалуйста! Как это победить?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте установить `postgresql-server-dev-XY`, где `XY` - версия вашего сервера, и он установит `libpq-dev`.

> apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.5 Чтение списков пакетов...
> Будут установлены следующие дополнительные пакеты: libpq-dev Предлагаемые пакеты:
> postgresql-doc-10 Будут установлены следующие НОВЫЕ пакеты: libpq-dev
> postgresql-server-dev-9.5

Comment: Я решил немного иначе, а точнее командой: sudo apt-get  install libpq-dev=12.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1